# What are the differences between `ToXXXX` and `AsXXXX` conversion methods?

Tags: .net, type-conversion, naming-conventions

Is there any semantic difference between `ToXXXX` conversion methods and `AsXXXX` conversion methods in the .NET framework?

Examples of such methods are `Object.ToString` and `Enumerable.AsEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If method returns the same instance but casted to another type, use AsXXX method.
If method consntructs new instance of unrelated type using object data, use ToXXX method.

Comment: The same thing has been mentioned in the book "Linq in Action".

Comment: What also helps me choose between `x.AsY()` and `x.ToY()` is that with the former, modifications to either `x` or the object returned by `x.AsY()` might affect the other, while with `x.ToY()`, both the original and the derived object can be modified independently from each other.